Remove "Machine Translated by Google" google api document translate
I am paying to use the Google api to translate document and google is adding Machine Translated by Google on each page.
I know this is part of the attribution requirements but if I specify it on my website it should not be required on the generated document.
const crypto = require('crypto')
const { TranslationServiceClient } = require('@google-cloud/translate').v3
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const fs = require('fs')

const translationClient = new TranslationServiceClient();
const parent = translationClient.locationPath('***', 'global');
const storage = new Storage();

async function translateFile({ uri, from, to }) {

    process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = './***.json'

    const pdfResponse = await fetch(uri);
    if (!pdfResponse.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Failed to download the PDF: ${response.statusText}`);
    }
    const buffer = await pdfResponse.buffer();

    const bucket = storage.bucket('***');
    const file = bucket.file(`${crypto.randomUUID()}.pdf`)
    await file.save(buffer)

    const inputUri = `gs://${bucket.name}/${file.name}`

    const documentInputConfig = { gcsSource: { inputUri } };

    const request = {
        parent,
        documentInputConfig: documentInputConfig,
        sourceLanguageCode: from,
        targetLanguageCode: to,
        //customizedAttribution: 'Test'
    };

    const [response] = await translationClient.translateDocument(request);

    await file.delete()

    fs.writeFileSync(`data/${crypto.randomUUID()}.pdf`, response.documentTranslation.byteStreamOutputs[0])
}

Seems like I can change it with customizedAttribution but each time I have an error Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid customized attribution: Test
The other solution as I let my user know it is translated by google will be a post process but remove text keeping background is not that simple with nodejs the only solution I have is to set a white rectangle on Machine Translated by Google there is no way to keep remove the background

It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
